# Content is not allowed in prolog - parsing json

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-studio

I'm attempting to use a json file to store user data for a dummy Android Studio project, and while trying to test the LoginActivity which reads in the file, I'm getting an error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> /Users/james/projects/cwm/app/src/debug/res/values/users.json:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "James",
      "email": "j@gmail.com",
      "address": "addr1",
      "password": "password",
      "usertype": "USER"
    },
    {
      "name": "Kayla",
      "email": "k@gmail.com",
      "address": "addr1",
      "password": "password",
      "usertype": "MANAGER"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the code in the LoginActivity that I believe is causing the error:

```
private String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("users.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}

private void parseJ() {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        if(jsonObject != null) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("users");
            if(jsonArray != null) {
                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(jo != null) {
                        String name = (String) jo.get("name");
                        String email = (String) jo.get("email");
                        String address = (String) jo.get("address");
                        String password = (String) jo.get("password");
                        String userType = (String) jo.get("usertype");

                        User u = new User(name, email, address, password);
                        u.setUserType(userType);
                        userList.put(email, u);
                        a.setMessage(u.toString());
                        a.show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I've searched stackoverflow and Google for a solution but most answers pertain to XML or JSON unmarshalling, which I don't believe is relevant to what I'm doing but I could be wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your users array doesn't have closing bracket. Is that what is causing error?

Comment: @BhalchandraSW I missed that in the copy pasting, this is only the first 2 of a longer list of users. Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/Users/james/projects/cwm/app/src/debug/**res**/values/users.json:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Please move your users.json from *res* folder to *assets* folder and try again.

Because, `getAssets()` method refers to `assets` folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) prevents deserialization. Check that your editor doesn't add one.

Comment: I'm using the Android Studio text editor that, I believe, is based on the IntelliJ platform. Does it add a BOM? How can I check and turn it off?

Comment: You can use any text editor that allows you to toggle BOM (e.g. Notepad++) to see if it's there and to turn it off. The text editor in Android Studio has never given me any issues though. Also check for invisible characters.